# Sorting table data from mySQL database

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I've got a website with a database over different phones. I would like to make a dropdown that will let the consumer sort and show/hide the phones after brand. I've created the dropdown as i want it, but my website isn't programmed by me, and i have very little experience with programming, so I really hope one of you guys or girls will help me out with how to code the PHP part.

I have a table that gets filled by a function in my home.php document, the whole function looks like this:

```
    public function filter()
{

    $price = $this->input->post('price');
    if ($price == '3000') {
        $price2 = '0';
    } else if ($price == '5500') {
        $price2 = '3000';
    } else if ($price == '6000') {
        $price = '10000';
        $price2 = '3500';
    }
    $size = $this->input->post('size');
    $type = $this->input->post('type');
    $design = $this->input->post('design');

    //echo "SELECT * FROM `product_info` WHERE `ac_price` > $price2 AND `ac_price` <= $price AND `design` = '$type' AND `size` = '$size' AND `type` = '$design' GROUP BY `id` ORDER BY `rating` DESC";die;
    $filter = $this->queries->custom("SELECT * FROM product_info GROUP BY model ORDER BY model ASC");


        if (count($filter) > 99) {
            $limits = 99;
        } else {
            $limits = count($filter);
        }
        if($this->input->post('more') == 'full'){
            $limits = count($filter);
        }
        if($this->input->post('more') == 'less'){
            $limits = 99;
        }
  {
        $rating = "";
        for ($a = 0; $a < $limits; $a++) {
            $detail_len = (strlen($filter[$a]->detail) > 100) ? '...' : '';
            for ($b = 0; $b < $filter[$a]->rating; $b++) {
                $rating .= '<span class="fa fa-star"></span>';
            }
            if ($filter[$a]->rating == 1) {
                for ($c = 0; $c < 4; $c++) {
                    $rating .= '<span style="color: #a2a1a0!important;" class="fa fa-star"></span>';
                }
            } elseif ($filter[$a]->rating == 2) {
                for ($c = 0; $c < 3; $c++) {
                    $rating .= '<span style="color: #a2a1a0!important;" class="fa fa-star"></span>';
                }
            } elseif ($filter[$a]->rating == 3) {
                for ($c = 0; $c < 2; $c++) {
                    $rating .= '<span style="color: #a2a1a0!important;" class="fa fa-star"></span>';
                }
            } elseif ($filter[$a]->rating == 4) {
                for ($c = 0; $c < 1; $c++) {
                    $rating .= '<span style="color: #a2a1a0!important;" class="fa fa-star"></span>';
                }
            }


            echo '
    <div class="col-md-4 get_attr" model="' . $filter[$a]->model . '" brand="' . $filter[$a]->brand . '" >
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 best">
                        <div class="col-md-12 best-img text-center">
                            <img src="' . base_url() . 'uploads/' . $filter[$a]->pic . '" alt="brand-one" style="height: 180px;">
                            <div class="flipdiv">
                                <div class="rating col-md-12 text-center nopad">
                                    ' . $rating . '
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Rating -->
                            <!-- Modal -->
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12 best-detail">
                            <table class="table table-bordered">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="display:none;">' . $filter[$a]->brand . '</td>
                                    <td style="display:none;">' . $filter[$a]->model . '</td>
                                    <td style="display:none;">' . $filter[$a]->ac_price . '</td>
                                    <td style="display:none;">' . $filter[$a]->ram . '</td>
                                    <td style="display:none;">' . $filter[$a]->processor . '</td>
                                    <td style="display:none;">' . $filter[$a]->size . '</td>
                                    <td style="display:none;">' . $filter[$a]->network . '</td>
                                    <td style="display:none;">' . $filter[$a]->pic . '</td>
                                    <td style="display:none;">' . $filter[$a]->detail . '</td>

                                    <td> M&aelig;rke </td>
                                    <td id="brand" style="display:none;" class="text-right">' . $filter[0]->brand . '</td>
                                    <td class="text-right">' . $filter[$a]->brand . '</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td> Model </td>
                                    <td id="model" style="display:none;" class="text-right">' . $filter[0]->model . '</td>
                                    <td class="text-right">' . $filter[$a]->model . '</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Pris</td>
                                    <td class="text-right">' . $filter[$a]->ac_price . ',00 kr.</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="vertical-align:middle!important; height:100px!important; line-height:25px!important;" colspan="2" class="text-center">' . substr($filter[$a]->detail, 0, 100) . ' ' . $detail_len . '</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm view_detail form-control"> Mere Information </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        ';
            $rating = "";
        }
    }
}
```

in my index.php file i've written this:

```
<section>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form>
            <select name="users" onchange="showBrand(this.value)">
                <option value="">Vælg Mærke:</option>
                <option value="1">Samsung</option>
                <option value="2">Apple</option>
                <option value="3">Huawei</option>
                <option value="4">Sony</option>
  </select>
</form>
  </div>
</section>


<script>




/* Initial Filters */
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $('.loader_div').fadeIn();
    var type = $('.type').val();
    var price = $('.price').val() ;
    var size = $('.ram').val();
    var design = $('.design').val();
    $.post('<?php echo base_url(); ?>mobiler/home/filter',function(data) {

        if (data == '') {
            $('.search_section').show();
            $('.no_result').show();
        }

        $('#filter_list').html(data);

        var brand = $('.get_attr').eq(0).attr('brand');
        var model = $('.get_attr').eq(0).attr('model');


/* Sorting Bar */

    function showBrand(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","<?php echo base_url(); ?>mobiler/home/showBrand"+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
```

The Jquery scripts are also active, as they are used on other parts of the site.

I know this is very bad formulated question, and a rather a cry for programming help, than an actual answer, and i'm sorry for that, but after two days with no progress what so ever, I have to try this.

I would like to sort after `'brand'` btw.